# Ansbile get the substring from task output

Tags: ansible

I have this URL string `server https://test.example.com:6443`. I need to extract only hostname `test` from it using Ansible task.
came up with this playbook, Is there a better way of doing this with-out using sed?

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - name: get the URL
      shell: echo 'server https://test.example.com:6443' |sed -e 's/^.*https...//' -e 's/\..*$//'
      register: result

    - name: Print the var
      debug:
        msg: "{{ result.stdout }}"
```

**Output**

```
PLAY [localhost] *********************************************************************************************************************

TASK [get the URL] *******************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [Print the var] *****************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "test"
}

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `split` on the URL name and get the desired value, Ideally hostname should be `test.example.com` in your case. However, you can customize the split function based on your need also as below.

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    url: "https://test.example.com:6443"

  tasks:

  - name: Print the hostname var
    debug:
      msg: "{{ url.split(':')[1].split('//')[1] }}"

  - name: Print the subdomain prefix
    debug:
      msg: "{{ url.split(':')[1].split('//')[1].split('.')[0] }}"
```